# While closing ImageInputStream thorws IOException

Tags: java

From many code snippets, it looks like it's necessary to close the ImageInputStream.

And under the spring framework, the method here:

```
public byte[] downloadImage(String imageUrl) throws Exception {

    UrlResource imageResource = new UrlResource(imageUrl);

    if (!imageResource.exists()) {

        log.warn("Try to download {}. And resource not exists.");

        throw new Exception("The image resource not exists.");

    }

    try (InputStream rawImageInputStream = imageResource.getInputStream();
         FastByteArrayOutputStream imageBytesStream = new FastByteArrayOutputStream()) {

        ImageInputStream imageInputStream
            = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(rawImageInputStream);

        Iterator<ImageReader> imageReaders = ImageIO.getImageReaders(imageInputStream);

        ImageReader imageReader = imageReaders.next();

        String fileExtension = imageReader.getFormatName();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageInputStream);

        ImageIO.write(image, fileExtension, imageBytesStream);

        imageBytesStream.flush();

        // throw exception
        imageInputStream.close(); 

        return imageBytesStream.toByteArray();

    }

}
```

However, this code snippet will cause throw IOException.

I'm wondering what's the reason ?

```
java.io.IOException: closed

at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.checkClosed(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:110)
at javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.close(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:857)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileCacheImageInputStream.close(FileCacheImageInputStream.java:250)
at tw.com.urad.service.web.DownloadImageServiceImpl.downloadImage(DownloadImageServiceImpl.java:56)
at tw.com.urad.service.web.DownloadImageServiceImplIntegrationTest.testDownloadImageSuccess(DownloadImageServiceImplIntegrationTest.java:35)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Thanks

Comment: Read the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream-. *Unlike most other methods in this class, this method does close the provided ImageInputStream after the read operation has completed*.

Comment: @JBNizet please write this in an answer, so that I can +1 it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ImageIO.read()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream-) closes the stream, as indicated in the javadoc:

> Unlike most other methods in this class, this method does close the provided ImageInputStream after the read operation has completed.

Comment: Thanks! It's really there :D